# Fetch SUM of columns above column

Tags: excel

I am building an excel formula, where i want to do something like below

Suppose i have `10 rows in excel sheet`

I have values in `B1 to B9,` i want to create a formula so that sum is shown in `C10`.
I know it is simple `=SUM(B1-B10)` but only in case when number of rows are fixed.

Whereas in my case, i also want this relation to work if i keep on adding any number of rows, so

`C(n) should always give a sum of B(1) to B(n-1)`

I have tried `indirect` but not able to use it convincingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `C10`

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B$1,0,0,ROW()-1,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you fix `C1=0`, the formula you should use is

```
[C2] =OFFSET(C2,-1,-1)+OFFSET(C2,-1,0)
```

and fill down.